# SQLAlchemy cursor.copy_from doesn't store dataframe

Tags: database, jupyter-notebook, sqlalchemy

I wrote a code in jupyter workbook that is working fine and as expecting:

```
def table_initiator(engine, table, data):
    connection = engine.raw_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql_request = f"""
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table};
        CREATE TABLE {table}
        (
          # table structure
        );
        GRANT ALL ON TABLE {table} TO user;
    """
    cursor.execute(sql_request)
    connection.commit()
    
    csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
    data.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False, header=False, sep='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

    # Use the COPY command to load the CSV file into the table
    csv_buffer.seek(0)
    cursor.copy_from(csv_buffer, table, sep="\t", null="")
    connection.commit()
    
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

as I mentioned - code is working fine and fast under jupyter.
But when I copied it to the python project and run under cmd command : python myscript.py the script doesn't store dataframe in the database.
Table is creating successfully. I see the structure and all privilege are correct.
I also checked the cursor - it returns "select" result from another table correctly as well.
But when I am trying to store data through copy_from I have nothing stored in.
What I checked:

1. versions of installed packages are the same (SQLAlchemy 1.4.50 and psycopg2 is 2.9.9)
2. dataframe has the body (it is not empty)
3. buffer is not empty

Engine is created by the :

```
def create_engine(eng):
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
            drivername="postgresql",
            username=eng.get('db_user'),
            password=eng.get('db_pass'),
            host=eng.get('db_host'),
            port='6432',
            database=eng.get('db_name'),
        ),
        echo_pool=True
    )
    return engine
```

Most funny thing: it is on the same computer but different GUI (Jupyter vs VSCode)

---

my findings:
I got a message error back from psycopg2 that the relation doest not exist (meaning table).
Table was created (as example public.my_table where public is scheme).
when I write a table name in the copy_from function as 'my_table' it starts working!

so, the difference in jupyter and vsc is the scheme name. Have no idea why it is so. Now, i am trying to play if IdentifierPreparer to get quoted table name.